# How can I express a range of floats that is greater than N and less than M?

Tags: ruby, range

I want a range of floats that is greater than N and less than M. This will include N:

```
N...M
```

And this will disclude all the numbers between N and N+1:

```
(N+1)...M
```

I suppose I could use the smallest positive float. This seems somewhat ugly, partially because it's possible to vary between systems/builds (I think?). But I guess even in that case it remains meaningful, so it seems like my best bet.

```
(N+Float::MIN)....M
```

Is there a nicer way to define a range that includes everything between N and M?

update: the purpose is to use the ranges in a case statement.

Comment: What is your purpose? Ruby's built-in range is usually used for iteration, which takes discrete values, and open intervals should not become an issue. If you want to do some mathematical operations, then you should define your custom range class.

Comment: The documentation of `Float::MIN` is wrong (integer!?). It's the minimum _normalized_ pos. float. Ruby actually doesn't expose the actual minimum float.

Comment: How about use a normal range with methods such as `class Range def cover_open?(r, x); x > r.begin && x < r.end(x); end`? I assume you realize that: `(1.1..2.3).to_a #=> TypeError: can't iterate from Float`.

Comment: I've modified my question and explained my purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Float#next_float`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Float.html#method-i-next_float) (introduced in Ruby 2.2):

```
N.next_float ... M
```